# How to handle CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, core-bluetooth

The property `CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate` of CBCharacteristic, that need to `writeValue: forCharacteristic:type:` or `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` or `readValueForCharacteristic:`? Thanks.